# Factory that creates a complex object tree

Tags: java, tree, factory-method

I've got a complex object tree that I need to instantiate. The object tree is a bunch of specialized classes that don't have a common root object (other than Object) and has generic objects (that I need to configure), and custom objects (all the "My" classes in the example code).

I've created the factory below to encapsulate the construction of this object tree, but this factory just seems too complex and hard to understand. Also when I'm trying to write a unit test for this factory it just seems very fragile because the test ends up trying to traverse the entire object tree to verify that all of the objects have been configured correctly, or the test ends up trying to test the combined behaviour of all the component objects which is a duplication of the unit tests of each individual component object.

How would you change this factory to simplify unit testing the factory that produces this complex object tree?

```java
public final class MyWidgetFactory
{
public static Widget createMyWidget(
        final ServiceA serviceA,
        final Factory<Metrics> metricsFactory,
        final String schemeName,
        final Serializer serializer)
{
    return createMyWidget(serviceA, metricsFactory, schemeName, serializer, CONTENT_TYPE_TO_DESCRIPTOR_MAP);
}

public static Widget createMyWidget(
        final ServiceA serviceA,
        final Factory<Metrics> metricsFactory,
        final String schemeName,
        final Serializer serializer,
        final Map<ContentType, MyFieldDescriptor> descriptorMap)
{
    final Widget proxied = new FilteringWidgetDecorator(
            new SimpleWidget(
                    getMyDataSource(serviceA, metricsFactory, descriptorMap),
                    getMyTransformer(metricsFactory,
                            schemeName,
                            descriptorMap,
                            serializer),
                    new NoValidator()),
            ImmutableList.of(
                    new ContentTypeWhilelistFilter(MY_WHITELISTED_CONTENT_TYPES)));

    return ProfiledInvocationHandler.getProfiledInstance(
            Widget.class, proxied, "MyWidget", metricsFactory);
}

private static Transformer getMyTransformer(
        final Factory<Metrics> metricsFactory,
        final String schemeName,
        final Map<ContentType, MyFieldDescriptor> descriptorMap,
        final Serializer serializer)
{
    final Transformer proxied =
            new FilteringTransformerDecorator(
                    ImmutableList.of(
                            new MyContentTypeFilter(
                                    getTransformerFilterVerificationStrategies(descriptorMap))),
                    true,
                    metricsFactory,
                    new StreamTransformer(
                            new SimpleNameSupplier(schemeName),
                            getSerializer(metricsFactory, serializer)));

    return ProfiledInvocationHandler.getProfiledInstance(
            Transformer.class, proxied, "MyTransformer", metricsFactory);
}

private static Map<ContentType, VerificationStrategy> getTransformerFilterVerificationStrategies(
        final Map<ContentType, MyFieldDescriptor> descriptorMap)
{
    return descriptorMap
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    (entry) -> {
                        return entry.getKey();
                    },
                    (entry) -> {
                        return entry.getValue().getDataStrategy().getVerificationStrategy();
                    }));
}

private static Serializer getSerializer(final Factory<Metrics> metricsFactory,
        final Serializer serializer)
{
    return ProfiledInvocationHandler.getProfiledInstance(
            Serializer.class, serializer, "serializer", metricsFactory);
}

private static DataSource getMyDataSource(final ServiceA serviceA,
        final Factory<Metrics> metricsFactory,
        final Map<ContentType, MyFieldDescriptor> descriptorMap)
{
    final DataSource proxied = new JoiningDataSource(
            descriptorMap
                    .entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .map(
                            (entry) -> {
                                final ContentType contentType = entry.getKey();
                                final MyFieldDescriptor descriptor = entry.getValue();
                                final DataStrategy dataStrategy = descriptor.getDataStrategy();

                                final DataSource dataSource =
                                        dataStrategy.getDataSource(serviceA, contentType);
                                if (descriptor.isRequired())
                                {
                                    return dataSource;
                                }
                                return new OptionalDataSource(dataSource);
                            })
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));

    return ProfiledInvocationHandler.getProfiledInstance(
            DataSource.class, proxied, "MyDataSource", metricsFactory);

}


static enum DataStrategy
{
    METADATA_ONLY
    {
        @Override
        public DataSource getDataSource(final ServiceA serviceA, final ContentType contentType)
        {
            return new MyDataSource(
                    serviceA,
                    contentType,
                    IS_EMPTY_OR_NUMERIC_PREDICATE,
                    (dataType) -> {
                        return DataType.METADATA.equals(dataType);
                    });
        }

        @Override
        public VerificationStrategy getVerificationStrategy()
        {
            return VerificationStrategy.METADATA_ONLY;
        }
    },
    DATA_AND_METADATA
    {
        @Override
        public DataSource getDataSource(final ServiceA serviceA, final ContentType contentType)
        {
            return new MyDataSource(
                    serviceA,
                    contentType,
                    IS_EMPTY_OR_NUMERIC_PREDICATE,
                    (dataType) -> {
                        return true;
                    });
        }

        @Override
        public VerificationStrategy getVerificationStrategy()
        {
            return VerificationStrategy.ALL;
        }
    };

    public abstract DataSource getDataSource(ServiceA serviceA, ContentType contentType);

    public abstract VerificationStrategy getVerificationStrategy();
}


static final class MyFieldDescriptor
{
    private MyFieldDescriptor(final DataStrategy dataStrategy, final boolean isRequired)
    {
        mDataStrategy = Preconditions.checkNotNull(dataStrategy, "dataStrategy must not be null");
        mIsRequired = isRequired;
    }

    public DataStrategy getDataStrategy()
    {
        return mDataStrategy;
    }

    public boolean isRequired()
    {
        return mIsRequired;
    }

    public static final class Builder
    {
        public Builder withDataStrategy(final DataStrategy dataStrategy)
        {
            mDataStrategy = dataStrategy;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withIsRequired(final boolean isRequired)
        {
            mIsRequired = isRequired;
            return this;
        }

        public MyFieldDescriptor build()
        {
            return new MyFieldDescriptor(mDataStrategy, mIsRequired);
        }

        private DataStrategy mDataStrategy;
        private boolean mIsRequired;
    }

    private final DataStrategy mDataStrategy;
    private final boolean mIsRequired;
}

static Predicate<Identifier> IS_EMPTY_OR_NUMERIC_PREDICATE =
        (identifier) -> {
            final String resourceId = identifier.getResourceIdentifier();
            return resourceId.isEmpty() || StringUtils.isNumeric(resourceId);
        };

static final Set<ContentType> MY_WHITELISTED_CONTENT_TYPES = ImmutableSet.of(
        ContentType.HTML);

static final Map<ContentType, MyFieldDescriptor> CONTENT_TYPE_TO_DESCRIPTOR_MAP =
        ImmutableMap.<ContentType, MyFieldDescriptor> builder()
                .put(ContentType.HTML,
                        new MyFieldDescriptor.Builder()
                                .withDataStrategy(DataStrategy.DATA_AND_METADATA)
                                .withIsRequired(true)
                                .build())
                .put(ContentType.EMAIL,
                        new MyFieldDescriptor.Builder()
                                .withDataStrategy(DataStrategy.DATA_AND_METADATA)
                                .withIsRequired(false)
                                .build())
                .put(ContentType.IMAGE,
                        new MyFieldDescriptor.Builder()
                                .withDataStrategy(DataStrategy.METADATA_ONLY)
                                .withIsRequired(false)
                                .build())
                .put(ContentType.VIDEO,
                        new MyFieldDescriptor.Builder()
                                .withDataStrategy(DataStrategy.METADATA_ONLY)
                                .withIsRequired(false)
                                .build())
                .build();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to CR! Mind sharing a little what's the objective (pun unintended) of this 'object tree'? Any examples to also demonstrate how and what are they used for?

Comment: the object tree process requests and encapsulates the details of what happens for one use case of processing these requests. for each request it filters the requests (at multiple levels of granularity), fetches extra data from serviceA, transforms the data (merges the extra data, removes unnecessary fields,...), then serialized the data for output. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much to comment on your more specific questions, but I figured I can chime in a little on parts of the code.

### `getTransformerFilterVerificationStrategies()`

There's just one simple but effective suggestion here, [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

You can specify one method reference for your key and one for the value. If you do not mind introducing a new method for `MyFieldDescriptor` that returns the verification strategy (following your somewhat *unconventional-for-Java* coding style):

```
static final class MyFieldDescriptor
{
    // ...

    public VerificationStrategy getVerificationStrategy()
    {
        return mDataStrategy.getVerificationStrategy();
    }
}
```

Then, the arguments used for `Collectors.toMap()` can be just:

```
return descriptorMap.entrySet().stream().collect(
            Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, MyFieldDescriptor::getVerificationStrategy));
```

### `getMyDataSource()`

I think you can slightly simplify your mapping function as such:

```
entry -> {
    final MyFieldDescriptor descriptor = entry.getValue();
    final DataSource dataSource = descriptor.getDataStrategy()
                                            .getDataSource(serviceA, entry.getKey());
    return descriptor.isRequired() ? dataSource : new OptionalDataSource(dataSource);
}
```

This reduces the reliance on temporary variables, and uses the ternary operator at the end for the `return` statement.

### `DataStrategy`

1. Since the only difference in instantiating `MyDataSource` is just on the `Predicate` as the final argument, perhaps you can also consider using said `Predicate` as a constructor argument for your `DataStrategy` enum values?
2. Same goes for `getVerificationStrategy()`, making these modifications can greatly simplify the approach here, especially when you do not require the enum values to implement the abstract methods.

Suggested edits:

```
static enum DataStrategy
{
    METADATA_ONLY(dataType -> DataType.METADATA.equals(dataType), 
                    VerificationStrategy.METADATA_ONLY),
    DATA_AND_METADATA(dataType -> true, VerificationStrategy.ALL);

    private final Predicate<DataType> mPredicate;
    private final VerificationStrategy mValidationStrategy;

    private DataStrategy(final Predicate<DataType> predicate, 
                            final VerificationStrategy validationStrategy)
    {
        mPredicate = predicate;
        mValidationStrategy = validationStrategy;
    }

    public DataSource getDataSource(final ServiceA serviceA, final ContentType contentType)
    {
        return new MyDataSource(
                serviceA,
                contentType,
                IS_EMPTY_OR_NUMERIC_PREDICATE,
                mPredicate);
    }

    public VerificationStrategy getVerificationStrategy()
    {
        return mVerificationStrategy;
    }
}
```

I have also taken the liberty to illustrate how the `Predicate<DataType>` lambda can be rewritten in a simplified form.

### Builder pattern for `MyFieldDescriptor`

A builder pattern is often suggested for classes if they require a number of constructor arguments, or if a [fluent interface](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) is strongly desired to provide additional context to how the class's properties can be construed through the builder.

Looking at `MyFieldDescriptor`, it only requires an `enum` and a `boolean`, which means it should be relatively trivial to simply use:

```
new MyFieldDescriptor(DataStrategy.DATA_AND_METADATA, true);
```

Compared to the builder approach:

```
new MyFieldDescriptor.Builder()
        .withDataStrategy(DataStrategy.DATA_AND_METADATA)
        .withIsRequired(true)
        .build();
```

Hence, I feel that using the builder pattern here may be somewhat cumbersome.